# How can I hide the authors'name for '\bibentry'?

Tags: bibentry

How to add an option to `\bibentry` so that the author's name can be hidden when not desired?

Here is an entry to test.

```
@Article{McCullochPitts/1943/LogicalCalculusIdeas,
  author    = {Warren S. McCulloch and Walter Pitts},
  journal   = {The Bulletin of Mathematical Biophysics},
  title     = {A logical calculus of the ideas immanent in nervous activity},
  year      = {1943},
  month     = {dec},
  number    = {4},
  pages     = {115--133},
  volume    = {5},
  groups    = {Computational model},
  publisher = {Springer Science and Business Media {LLC}},
}
```